# field values are not getting populated after insertion of List (though the record is created)

Tags: apex

Basically I want to insert values some field values into the respected fields into child object Trademark_Details_ESR__c from the custom Object Trademark_Details__c dynamically for that i have created custom settings TrademarkESRDetails__c.Ihave got all the required values into the esrList but those are not populated after its insertion.

Here is my code.

```
public with sharing class CreateTrademarkDetailsESRGateway{

    public list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c> TMESR=new list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c>();
    public list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c> newESR=new list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c>();
    public String input;
    public Integer index=0;
    public map<Integer,list<TrademarkESRDetails__c>> esrmap=new map<Integer,list<TrademarkESRDetails__c>>();

   // public list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c> esrList = new list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c>();
    public list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c> esrList;

    public void DetailsUpdate(list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c> triggernew){ 


        for(Trademark_Details_ESR__c tempTM: triggernew){
            system.Debug('---tempTM--'+tempTM); 
            system.Debug('---tempTM.BMCID__c--'+tempTM.BMCID__c);
            input=tempTM.BMCID__c;
            system.Debug('---input--'+input); 
        }

        if(input!= null){
            system.Debug('---input--'+input);
            list<Trademark_Details__c>  tmrRecords = [Select id,Application_Date__c,Application_No__c,Application_Status__c,
                                                       Brand_Name__c,   Class_No__c,Contact_Email__c,Contact_Name__c,
                                                       Contact_Phone__c,Operation_Name__c,oid__c,User_Date__c,name
                                                       From 
                                                       Trademark_Details__c
                                                       Where
                                                       oid__c =: input AND Application_Status__c='Objected'];   

             system.debug('-tmrRecords-' + tmrRecords);
             getESRDetails(tmrRecords);
       }
    }


    public void getESRDetails(list<Trademark_Details__c> tmrRecords1){

    try{
        system.debug('---TMRRecords1'+TMRRecords1);
        system.debug('---TMRRecords1.size()---'+TMRRecords1.size());
        system.debug('--- TrademarkESRDetails__c.getAll()-'+ TrademarkESRDetails__c.getAll());
        system.debug('--- TrademarkESRDetails__c.getAll().Values()---'+ TrademarkESRDetails__c.getAll().Values());

        list<TrademarkESRDetails__c> lst = [Select ESR_Field_API_Name__c,TM_Field_API_Name__c,List_Size__c from TrademarkESRDetails__c];
        system.debug('---lst'+lst);

        for (TrademarkESRDetails__c  temp : TrademarkESRDetails__c.getAll().Values()) {
                system.debug('---temp---'+temp);
                system.debug('---temp.List_Size__c---'+integer.valueof(temp.List_Size__c));
                if(esrMap.containsKey(integer.valueof(temp.List_Size__c))){
                    esrMap.get(integer.valueof(temp.List_Size__c)).add(temp);
                    system.Debug('in IF-esrMap.get(integer.valueof(temp.List_Size__c))-' + esrMap.get(integer.valueof(temp.List_Size__c))); 
                }else{
                    esrMap.put(integer.valueof(temp.List_Size__c), new List<TrademarkESRDetails__c> {temp});
                    system.Debug('in else -esrMap.get(integer.valueof(temp.List_Size__c))-' + esrMap.get(integer.valueof(temp.List_Size__c)));
                }   
        }
        system.debug('-esrMap.size-' + esrMap.size()+'---esrMap---'+esrMap);
        system.debug('---esrmap.get(index)---'+esrMap.get(index));

        /*for(Trademark_Details__c tempTM: tmrRecords1){
            system.debug('---TMRRecords11---'+tempTM);
            //TrademarkESRDetails__c is a custom settings
            for(TrademarkESRDetails__c customSettings :esrmap.get(index)){
               system.debug('---customSettings'+customSettings);
               esr.put(customSettings.ESR_Field_API_Name__c, tempTM.get(customSettings.TM_Field_API_Name__c));
               system.debug('---esr1'+esr);
               break;
            }
            index++;
        }*/

       // sObject s;
       // Trademark_Details_ESR__c esr = (Trademark_Details_ESR__c)s;

        Trademark_Details_ESR__c esr=new Trademark_Details_ESR__c();

        for(Trademark_Details__c tempTM: tmrRecords1){
            system.debug('---TMRRecords11---'+tempTM + '-esr-' + esr);
            //TrademarkESRDetails__c is a custom settings

            for(TrademarkESRDetails__c customSettings : esrmap.get(index)){
               system.debug('---customSettings--'+customSettings + '-esrmap.get(index)-'+esrmap.get(index));
               esr.put(customSettings.ESR_Field_API_Name__c, tempTM.get(customSettings.TM_Field_API_Name__c));
               system.debug('---esr1--'+esr);
               esrList = new list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c>();
               esrList.add(esr);
            }
            index++; 
        }

        system.debug('-esrList.size-' + esrList.size()+ '-esrList-' + esrList);

        if(esrList.size()>0){
            system.debug('--inside if'+esrList);
            insert esrList;
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        system.debug('---Exception'+e.getmessage());
    }
   }
}
```

Please free to revert if any clarification is required.
Contact Details:
EmailId:ankit.bobde@bmcgroup.in

Regards,
Ankit

Comment: You are calling `esrList = new list<Trademark_Details_ESR__c>();` on every iteration of your `for loop`. That means that `esrList` will only ever have 1 record at most. You should only initialize the list once outside of the loop.

Comment: I have initialized the esrList publicly outside the loop ..but still values are not populating and now it is showing an exception "Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements"

Comment: Thanks for your response BarCotter. As you have said I have initialized the esrList publicly outside the loop ..but still values are not populating and now it is showing an exception "Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements".

Comment: That happens when you call `esrList.add(esr);` twice for the same instance of `esr`

Comment: I have initialized the list inside inner for loop to create new instance of esr every time and resolved the exception as well but now the thing is it had created 12(Note: for e.g. as per the records size) lists and getting inserted as 12 rows but field values are still not populated.Here is my code in the following comment.

Comment: for(TrademarkESRDetails__c customSettings : esrmap.get(index)){
               Trademark_Details_ESR__c esr=new Trademark_Details_ESR__c();
               system.debug('---customSettings--'+customSettings + '-esrmap.get(index)-'+esrmap.get(index));
               esr.put(customSettings.ESR_Field_API_Name__c, tempTM.get(customSettings.TM_Field_API_Name__c));
               system.debug('---esr1--'+esr);
               esrList.add(esr);
            }

Answer (score 0):

I have initialized the esrList publicly outside the loop ..but still values are not populating and now it is showing an exception "Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements"